# вращение маршрута движения

Tags: java, javafx

У меня есть задание, состоящее из нескольких пунктов:

**Разработать программу, обеспечивающую:**

a)  ввод произвольного многоугольника и замкнутого маршрута движения, анимацию (движение) построенной фигуры вдоль маршрута (5б.);

b)  редактирование построенного маршрута движения путем «перетаскивания» вершин (5б.);

c)  вращение фигуры в процессе движения (5 б.).

d)  вращение маршрута движения (5 б.)

e)  задача локализации точки в треугольнике  (5 б.);

Меня интересует пункт D и E. Но первым делом пункт D.

Вращение маршрута, я понимаю как: Допустим у нас есть секундная стрелка, которая является траекторией движения моего многоугольника. Она должна изменяться. Я не понимаю, как изменять траекторию движения, если функция start запускается 1 раз.

Код:

```
package com.example.vrashenie;

import javafx.animation.PathTransition;
import javafx.animation.RotateTransition;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.shape.Polygon;
import javafx.scene.shape.Shape;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;

public class PolygonAnimation extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Pane root = new Pane();

        // Ввод многоугольника
        double[] polygonPoints = {100, 100, 200, 50, 300, 100, 200, 200};
        Polygon polygon = new Polygon(polygonPoints);

        // Создание маршрута
        Shape path = polygon; // Можно изменить маршрут по вашему желанию

        // Создание анимации движения по маршруту
        PathTransition pathTransition = new PathTransition();
        pathTransition.setNode(polygon);
        pathTransition.setPath(path);
        pathTransition.setCycleCount(PathTransition.INDEFINITE);
        pathTransition.setAutoReverse(false);
        pathTransition.setDuration(Duration.seconds(1)); // Продолжительность анимации в секундах

        // Создание анимации вращения вокруг своей оси
        RotateTransition rotateTransition = new RotateTransition();
        rotateTransition.setNode(polygon);
        rotateTransition.setByAngle(360); // Угол вращения в градусах
        rotateTransition.setCycleCount(RotateTransition.INDEFINITE);
        rotateTransition.setDuration(Duration.seconds(1)); // Продолжительность вращения в секундах

        // Запуск обеих анимаций
        pathTransition.play();
        rotateTransition.play();

        root.getChildren().add(polygon);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 400, 300);
        primaryStage.setTitle("Rotating Polygon Animation");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Сейчас у меня траектория равна моему многоугольнику. Можно ли как-то сделать движения по прямой, чтобы эта траектория менялась?? Помогите пожалуйста, я уже очень много времени не могу понять, как это сделать.

У меня есть код, где мой многоугольник двигается по прямой траектории, но как её изменить не понимаю.

Доп. код (тут движение по прямой)

```
package com.example.vrashenie;

import javafx.animation.PathTransition;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.shape.Line;
import javafx.scene.shape.Polygon;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;

public class RotatingPathAnimation extends Application {
    

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Pane root = new Pane();

        // Создание многоугольника
        double[] polygonPoints = {100, 100, 150, 50, 200, 100, 150, 150};
        Polygon polygon = new Polygon(polygonPoints);

        // Создание прямой траектории
        Line line = new Line(150, 50, 350, 150);
//        Line line2 = new Line(150, 50, 350, 180);

        // Создание анимации движения по траектории
        PathTransition pathTransition = new PathTransition();
        pathTransition.setNode(polygon);
        pathTransition.setPath(line);
        pathTransition.setCycleCount(PathTransition.INDEFINITE);
        pathTransition.setAutoReverse(true);
        pathTransition.setDuration(Duration.seconds(2)); // Продолжительность анимации в секундах

        // Запуск анимации
        pathTransition.play();

        root.getChildren().add(polygon);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 400, 300);
        primaryStage.setTitle("Clockwise Animation");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();

//        // Создание дополнительной анимации
//        PathTransition additionalPathTransition = new PathTransition();
//        additionalPathTransition.setNode(polygon);
//        additionalPathTransition.setPath(line2);
//        additionalPathTransition.setCycleCount(PathTransition.INDEFINITE);
//        additionalPathTransition.setAutoReverse(true);
//        additionalPathTransition.setDuration(Duration.seconds(2));
//
//        // Запуск дополнительной анимации
//        additionalPathTransition.play();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```